# If Statement Not Displaying Results

Tags: javascript, html

So the rest of the code works as I need it too. The only part that doesn't work is listed below. What I am trying to accomplish is if the `SENTINEL` is entered once the program is initiated, `numResults` and `floatResults` will receive the following values. Where did I not code properly so the statement doesn't work? Thank you for the help

**if statement giving me the issue**

```
// gives value if only the SENTINEL is entered once program is initiated
  if (number == SENTINEL && numValues == 0 && floatValues == 0 ) {
    numResults = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
    floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
  }
```

**My Code**

```
<script>

        function examineNumbers() {

const SENTINEL = -1;

let number = 0;
let type;
let numValues = 0;
let numAverage = 0;
let floatValues = 0;
let numTotal = 0;
let floatTotal = 0;
let list = document.getElementById("list");
let numbers = document.getElementById("numbers");
let floating = document.getElementById("floating");


// while loop to only allow numbers greater than zero to be inputted
while (number != SENTINEL) {
  number = prompt("Enter a number. Type " + SENTINEL + " to stop.");
  if (number == -1) {
    break;
  }
  // deterrmines if a number is even
  if (number % 2 == 0) {
    type = " is an even value";
    numTotal += parseInt(number);
    numValues++;
  }

  // determines if a number is odd
  else if (Math.abs(number % 2) == 1) {
    type = " is an odd value";
    numTotal += parseInt(number);
    numValues++;
  }

  // gives a floating point type if above two aren't met
  else {
    type = " is a floating point value.";
    floatTotal += parseFloat(number);
    numTotal += parseFloat(number);
    numValues++;
    floatValues++;
  }

  let numResults;
  let floatResults;
  // averages non floating numbers
  numAverage = numTotal / numValues;
  numResults = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " The total is " + numTotal.toFixed(2) +
    " and the average is " + numAverage.toFixed(2) + ".";

   // gives value if only the SENTINEL is entered once program is initiated
  if (number == SENTINEL && numValues == 0 && floatValues == 0 ) {
    numResults = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
    floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
  }

  // averages floating point numbers
  floatAverage = floatTotal / floatValues;
  floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = "The sum of just the floating point values is " + floatTotal.toFixed(2) +
    " with the average of " + floatAverage.toFixed(2) + ".";


  // gives value if no floating numbers are entered
  if (floatValues == 0 ) {
    floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = "No floating-pont values were entered."
  }


  let li = "";
  //only add number and its status to list when number not equal to SENTINEL
  if (number !== SENTINEL) {
    li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = number + type;
    list.appendChild(li);

    // displays information for both non floating numbers and floating numbers
    numbers.innerHTML = numResults;
    floating.innerHTML = floatResults;
  }
}
}
    </script>
```

```
<h1>Number Examination Tool </h1>

<form name="myForm" >

         <button type="button" onclick="examineNumbers();">Click here to enter numbers </button>

    <h3>List of Numbers </h3>  

    <ul id = "list"></ul> 

    <div id="numbers"></div>

    <div id="floating"></div>

    </form>
```

Comment: looks like your missing some some quotes in your if statement `number == "SENTINEL"` if your saying `== SENTINEL` your asking if its equal to a variable named `SENTINEL`

Comment: I do have a variable listed as ````SENTINEL````. The value of it is ````-1```` and its what breaks the loop.

Comment: oh sorry, i had scrolled past it and couldn't see it declared anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking the IF statement so it never gets to the end, if you move the IF statement like below

```
number = prompt("Enter a number. Type " + SENTINEL + " to stop.");
  // gives value if only the SENTINEL is entered once program is initiated
  if (number == SENTINEL && numValues == 0 && floatValues == 0 ) {
    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
    document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
    while (list.children.length>0) {
      list.lastChild.remove()
    }
  }
  if (number == -1) {
    break;
  }
```

It should work, Or you can combine the statement,

```
number = prompt("Enter a number. Type " + SENTINEL + " to stop.");
  // gives value if only the SENTINEL is entered once program is initiated
  if (number == -1) {
    if (numValues == 0 && floatValues == 0) {
      document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
      document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = " No values 
were entered."
      while (list.children.length>0) {
        list.lastChild.remove()
      }
    }
    break;
  }
```

Comment: hmmmm I am only getting it to output to the ````numbers.innerHTML = numResults;```` and not the ````floating.innerHTML = floatResults;
  ```` as well

Comment: try it now, just had to remove the left hand side

Comment: that worked. Now quick question. A problem I just noticed. If I run a running list with mixed numbers and break the program, then initiate a new instance of the program and just enter the ````SENTINEL```` the list of numbers from the past instance remains despite showing the value of ````No values were entered````. How do I get the list to clear on each run?

Comment: I added an edit to clear the list with a while loop that removes all the elements from it

Comment: Ah ok. I was attempting something similar but wasn't quite there. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

To set the values into numResults, floatResults each then each variables should be defined first. To put number variable into prompt then I put the if condition  under number prompt. Seems everything is fine.

```html
<script>

// gives value if only the SENTINEL is entered once program is initiated
  if (number == SENTINEL && numValues == 0 && floatValues == 0 ) {
    numResults = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
    floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
  }


        function examineNumbers() {

const SENTINEL = -1;

let number = 0;
let type;
let numValues = 0;
let numAverage = 0;
let floatValues = 0;
let numTotal = 0;
let floatTotal = 0;
let list = document.getElementById("list");
let numbers = document.getElementById("numbers");
let floating = document.getElementById("floating");


// while loop to only allow numbers greater than zero to be inputted
while (number != SENTINEL) {
  number = prompt("Enter a number. Type " + SENTINEL + " to stop.");
  if (number == SENTINEL && numValues == 0 && floatValues == 0 ) {

  floating.innerHTML = " No values were entered."
  numbers.innerHTML = " No values were entered."
    break;
  }
  // deterrmines if a number is even
  if (number % 2 == 0) {
    type = " is an even value";
    numTotal += parseInt(number);
    numValues++;
  }

  // determines if a number is odd
  else if (Math.abs(number % 2) == 1) {
    type = " is an odd value";
    numTotal += parseInt(number);
    numValues++;
  }

  // gives a floating point type if above two aren't met
  else {
    type = " is a floating point value.";
    floatTotal += parseFloat(number);
    numTotal += parseFloat(number);
    numValues++;
    floatValues++;
  }

  let numResults;
  let floatResults;
  // averages non floating numbers
  numAverage = numTotal / numValues;
  numResults = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " The total is " + numTotal.toFixed(2) +
    " and the average is " + numAverage.toFixed(2) + ".";

   // gives value if only the SENTINEL is entered once program is initiated
  if (number == SENTINEL && numValues == 0 && floatValues == 0 ) {
    numResults = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
    floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = " No values were entered."
  }

  // averages floating point numbers
  floatAverage = floatTotal / floatValues;
  floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = "The sum of just the floating point values is " + floatTotal.toFixed(2) +
    " with the average of " + floatAverage.toFixed(2) + ".";


  // gives value if no floating numbers are entered
  if (floatValues == 0 ) {
    floatResults = document.getElementById("floating").innerHTML = "No floating-pont values were entered."
  }


  let li = "";
  //only add number and its status to list when number not equal to SENTINEL
  if (number !== SENTINEL) {
    li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = number + type;
    list.appendChild(li);

    // displays information for both non floating numbers and floating numbers
    numbers.innerHTML = numResults;
    floating.innerHTML = floatResults;
  }
}
}
    </script>

<h1>Number Examination Tool </h1>

<form name="myForm" >

         <button type="button" onclick="examineNumbers();">Click here to enter numbers </button>

    <h3>List of Numbers </h3>  

    <ul id = "list"></ul> 

    <div id="numbers"></div>

    <div id="floating"></div>

    </form>
```